# Why increase of Y divided by increase of X in slope equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, slope

In the slope equation,the increase of x is divided to the increase of y.But I cannot understand,why we cannot use the increase of y is divide to the increase of x.Everyone said,the gradient of the tangent to the curve at a point is one over one,increase in y divided by increase in x,etc....But they cannot tell why the increase of Y divide by increase of X and why we cannot use the increase of x divided by increase of y.

Comment: Yes, that would give as much information as "change in y divided by change in x".  But we need to choose one way or the other to have a specific function and chose to use "change in y divided by change in x".   One reason for that **choice** is that we tend to think (though it is not *mathematically* required) of the function y= f(x) as "a value of x **causes** a change in y".  A **change**  in x causes a **change** in y.  "Change in y divided by change in x" answers "how much change in y is caused by change in x?"\cdot\cdot\cdot$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a constant function, for example. You would say that the slope equals zero in that case. For an arbitrary increase in x, the increase of y would be zero, so x/y would not be defined. It doesn't make sense that way considering that the slope is meant to increase when the increase of y is bigger along a constant difference in x.